# App crashing on navigation due to react-native-webview?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-webview, react-native-video

I am using react-native-webview in my code. It is used under the scrollview. But due to it app is crashing when I pressing back button or navigating to another screen.

Below is my react native video code

```
 <WebView
  useWebKit
  originWhitelist={["*"]}
  style={{ width: "100%", height: carMapViewHeight }}
  source={{ uri: carMapURL }}
  mixedContentMode="compatibility"
  onLoadEnd={() =>
    this.setState({
      isMapLoaded: true,
    })
  }
/>
```

I tried one solution using **androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={true}**. It is working but my react-native-video has stopped playing after that.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please , can you reproduce the bug in sandbox - codesandbox.io/s/react-native-q4qymyp2l6?from-embed=&file=/… or snack.expo.dev , it will be much easier to me help you with all code

Answer (score 1):

try adding removeClippedSubviews={true}  to your scrollview
[reference taken from here..which worked for me](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/214)